# How to target a variable's child with JQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, target

How do I target **post_ad_cloned's** input child?

```
var post_ad = $('.duplicate_name'); 
var post_ad_cloned = post_ad.clone().removeClass('duplicate_name').appendTo('#sss').show();
$("post_ad_cloned input").css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var post_ad = $('.duplicate_name'); 
var post_ad_cloned = post_ad.clone().removeClass('duplicate_name').appendTo('#sss').show();
$("input", post_ad_cloned).css('color', 'red');
```

or:

```
var post_ad = $('.duplicate_name'); 
var post_ad_cloned = post_ad.clone()
  .removeClass('duplicate_name')
  .appendTo('#sss')
  .show()
  .children('input')
    .css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Thank you yoavmatchulsky. Perfect!